# JsonArray Or JsonObject is null while parsing with JsonReader

Tags: android, json, android-parser, jsonreader

I am trying to parse a json using JsonReader. While parsing I came accross 2 scenarios where my app crashes.
1). When JsonArray contains sets of another JsonArrays and and out of which one of it is null. I am giving a scenarios where result is a array and it has 21 more arrays in it and the last array is null.

```
"results": [(21)
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[...(5)],-
[(0)]
],
```

2). When JsonArray has sets of objects in it and one of the object is null. I have attached the example for the same. Here I have source as my JsonArray which contains 21 objects and out of which 1 is null.

```
"source": [(21)
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
{...},-
null
]
```

I am able to check when some individual element within a is null by

```
reader.peek()== JsonToken.NULL
```

Error Output in Logcat:

```
02-04 16:10:02.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-1-thread-2
02-04 16:10:02.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1203): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NULL at line 1 column 327992
02-04 16:10:02.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.expect(JsonReader.java:339)
02-04 16:10:02.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1203):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:322)
```

I cant figure out how can I check whether Array or Object which I want to parse which has no name is Null or not.

Edit:

Code:

```
public ResultObject parse(){
    try{
        if(reader != null ){
            resultObject    =    new ResultObject();
            reader.beginObject();
            Log.e("123", "inside try ");
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                String name = reader.nextName();
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
                    if(reader.peek()== JsonToken.NULL){
                        reader.skipValue();
                        id=    0;
                        Log.e("123", "parse result --------id----------" + id);
                        resultObject.setId(id);
                    }else{
                        id= reader.nextDouble();
                        Log.e("123", "parse result -------id----------" + id);
                        resultObject.setId(id);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("123", "skip value");
                    reader.skipValue();
                }
            }

            reader.endObject();
        }
    }catch(IOException e){ 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resultObject;
}
```

Calling function:

```
if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(SOURCE)) {
    if(reader.peek()== JsonToken.NULL){
        reader.skipValue();
    } else {
        resultObjectList = new ArrayList();
        resultObject    =    new ResultObject();
        reader.beginArray();
        while(reader.hasNext()){
            resultObject    =new ResultJsonUtil(reader).parse();
            if(resultObject!=null){
                resultObjectList.add(resultObject);
            }
        }

        reader.endArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your code, where it is crashing.

Comment: @OlafDietsche - i have added the code for case 2 where a object is being null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code crashes at `reader.beginObject();`, it seems. Since there is not an object, Gson throws an exception.

If you're not sure, what comes next, you can test this with [`peek`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html#peek%28%29)

> Returns the type of the next token without consuming it.

You can then call the proper reader method according to the retrieved [`JsonToken`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonToken.html)

```
if (reader.peek() != JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT) {
    // do something
} else {
    // parse object
    resultObject = new ResultObject();
    reader.beginObject();
    ...
}
```